# Using Ember-CLI with MVC .Net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ember.js

I am trying to use Ember-CLI and MVC .Net together. I have the ember app building with the CLI and I am trying to return View("~/ui/dist/index.html") in the MVC controller and it says

"The view '~/ui/dist/index.html' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/ui/dist/index.html"

the file is in the location so I am not sure why it is not working.

The ember app itself was working before embedded in a cshtml file, but I am migrating it into the CLI.

I was using this as a reference to setup my project https://stackoverflow.com/a/28972677/4228237. "ui" in the path above is the ember-cli app name