# How to combine ASP MVC 5 and Emberjs

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, ember.js

I am trying to experiment with ASP MVC 5 and Emberjs. I dont want to create full-fledge WebAPI that emberjs will serve. What I want is to mix both and use emberjs for data driven pages and razor view for simple pages.

So far I just tried ember-cli because I dont know how to build the emberjs app when combined with asp mvc.

My question is how to automatically import and compile the templates and js related to emberjs to be used on my asp mvc razor views?

Also I've read about es6 module in ember-cli, I dont know if its necessary to solve my problem.

Comment: This might be a start http://www.hutchinson.io/ember-cli-and-asp-net/, do something similar but in an mvc project.

Comment: And actually this answer would be even better information http://stackoverflow.com/a/28972677/2482265

Comment: I actually hit that stackoverflow question a while ago but my brain is not capable of processing the answer ;)

Would you mind to explain it further?

Answer (score 2):

You'll likely want to use ember-cli to first build your Ember application using `ember build` ([reference](https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#using-ember-cli)). Then ensure the output of `build` command (likely in the `/dist` folder unless you specified a different output path) is in a place that your Asp.Net MVC application has visibility of.

You can serve your newly built assets from your MVC application like this:

```
return File(Server.MapPath("~/my-ember-app/dist/") + "index.html", "text/html");
```

If your Ember application is located in the same folder as your Asp.Net MVC application each time you run `ember build` the new output should be sent to browser when the associate MVC route returns `index.html`.